# Showing a new mail in INBOX using IMAP in Pantomime Framework

Tags: objective-c, imap, pantomime

I am creating a mail client using IMAP (It is a mac application using Pantomime framework). I am able to fetch all messages and folders etc.

When a new mail is recieved it is shown when the user logs-out and then logs-in again.

Is there any event that is fired when a new mail is received ? or Is there any other way I can show the user about new messages ?

Thanks

Comment: I've heard better things about MailCore. Besides, Pantomime is under the LGPL license, which forbids you to use it in a commercial product.  Make sure you know the license before you spend a lot of work implementing that library.

Answer (score 0):

You need to fire a timer which send noop command to server and repeat this for a set time interval. Then if there are new mails you will get the new mails in response from server. Then you can parse response and display to user.